# Don’t upvote duplicate answers

Tags: discussion

Folks, we have had a few instances of new “users” posting answers that are copy and pastes of other people’s answers. Examples [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32779/5) and [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32783/5), for those that can view deleted answers.

Some of these are from known spammers, and we believe that they are hoping to get a few unwitting upvotes so that they can get enough reputation points to post lots of (spam) posts in quick succession.

So please be alert when you upvote or clean up new users’ answers, that they aren’t just a copy and paste of someone else’s.

Thanks

Comment: If we find one of these, should we flag it for moderator attention?

Comment: @belisarius Got two! http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32859/5478 now they're probably waiting for a good moment to spam.

Comment: @m_goldberg Yes, please.

Comment: @Kuba Sorry, my brain is leaking. What do you mean?

Comment: @belisarius oh, just not very bright joke, I've linked the question marked duplicate which you and Michael have answered. Hope you don't mind ;) I know this case doesn't fit the description :)

Comment: @Kuba :) Upvoted your comment :D

Comment: I've just realized that both of the spammers copied my answers. Could this be a mere coincidence or do these "robots" choose target templates based on some criteria that they share? This is creepy, but let me stress here that I have no relation to any of them!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the First Post review queue only shows the specific answer and corresponding question, not the other questions. This is a bit of a problem.